# 공시가격 열람 - reviewing of official price?

Tags: word-usage

공시가격 열람 - what is the meaning of 열람? In the dictionary, its translated like "reading".

I assume in this context it means "review" of official price, right? Deciding whether the price is optimal\correct. Or correcting official prices to optimal level.

Comment: It means to see the official price. The reason they put the word 열람 in this context is just they wanted to use the most formal vocabulary for 보다(to see).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"열람" usually means something more than reading. We use "열람" for a specific reading.

For example, if you just read a book in your home, we don't use "열람" for that. If you read a newspaper, we don't use "열람" for that.

However, if you go to a library or a government office building, find a list of the official price history of a land in the place, and take a look at the data, we use "열람" for that.

"열람" in "공시가격 열람" could mean "review". It doesn't matter whether it is for deciding whether the price is optimal, correct, wrong, etc. The activity itself is "열람".